# HTTPS REST call from salesforce returns error

Tags: api, rest, https, callout

I am trying to call a end point using following code, but it always returns the below error.

Can you suggest what is the possible error?

```
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setEndpoint('https://ntrs-com.apibasicauth.btglss.net/bitglassapi/data/v1/soql');
req.setMethod('POST');
//req.setHeader('Authorization', '');
req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
req.setBody('{"responseformat":"json","query":"select Id from Account","offset":"1","limit":"10"}');
Http http = new Http();
HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
System.debug('---Body----'+res.getBody());
```

Error says:

> Line: 8, Column: 1 System.CalloutException:
>   java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative DNS
>   name matching ntrs-com.apibasicauth.btglss.net found.

Comment: You are receiving this error because the domain names mentioned in the SSL certificate do not match the domain name `ntrs-com.apibasicauth.btglss.net`.

The SSL certificate currently installed supports the following domains:
 
Common name: *.bitglass.net

SANs: *.bitglass.net, bitglass.net, *.btglss.net, btglss.net, *.bgsecure.net, bgsecure.net

Source:
https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html?submit=submit&hostname=ntrs-com.apibasicauth.btglss.net

Comment: Do we need to change the end point?

Comment: Yes, if you can. The SSL certificate has a SAN wildcard domain name of `*.btglss.net`. To match this, you should change the domain name from `ntrs-com.apibasicauth.btglss.net` to **`ntrs-com-apibasicauth.btglss.net`**. Note, "." is replaced by "-" in the subdomain.